# Is it possible to merge different vector types in qgis

Tags: qgis

I would like to merge a point vector layer with a polygon layer. There are some attributes in the polygon layer which I would like to be in the point layer!

Comment: Have you tried "Join attributes by location", or "Intersect"? They wont be merged but the attributes will get transferred

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works